# getInitialMessage callback gets null value when flutter app is terminated after the arrival of FCM notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I receive a notification in foreground, "on-Message" call-back gets the message data and then I terminated my app. Then I tap the notification after termination of application and "  get-Initial-Message" call-back is triggered but the data is null. I don't know when I terminate application after notification arrival , the notification data is wiped off.

tried to navigate to a screen in this scenario but the notification data is null to display

Comment: Please share the code of your `onMessage` callback.